# failure: nginx-1.0.15-12.el6.x86_64.rpm from epel

Tags: linux, nginx, centos, epel

I'm trying to install Nginx in Linux Centos 6.7

I log-in as root and run

`yum update`

`yum install nginx -y`

I keep getting

> nginx-1.0.15-12.el6.x86_64: failure: nginx-1.0.15-12.el6.x86_64.rpm from epel: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.

Any hint/suggestion on that will be much appreciated

---

## Try #2

Try `yum clean metadata` then `yum install nginx -y` , I got

```
[root@CentOS6 ~]# yum install nginx -y
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/metalink                                                                                                                                                 |  12 kB     00:00     
 * base: mirror.solarvps.com
 * epel: ftp.cse.buffalo.edu
 * extras: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
 * remi-php56: mirrors.mediatemple.net
 * remi-safe: mirrors.mediatemple.net
 * updates: mirror.net.cen.ct.gov
base                                                                                                                                                          | 3.7 kB     00:00     
base/primary_db                                                                                                                                               | 4.6 MB     00:00     
epel                                                                                                                                                          | 4.3 kB     00:00     
epel/primary_db                                                                                                                                               | 3.6 MB     00:00     
Error: xz compression not available
```

---

## Try #3

`yum install pyliblzma` or `yum install python-backports-lzma`

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.solarvps.com
 * epel: ftp.cse.buffalo.edu
 * extras: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
 * remi-php56: mirrors.mediatemple.net
 * remi-safe: mirrors.mediatemple.net
 * updates: mirror.trouble-free.net
Error: xz compression not available
```

Comment: What epel configuration do you have? What errors are reported above that (if any)? Does cleaning your yum cache help (`yum clean metadata`)?

Comment: I know none of that. But sure, I'll try clean them first.

Comment: I update my post base on your suggestion, and I got `Error: xz compression not available`

Comment: Try `yum install pyliblzma` or `yum install python-backports-lzma` first?

Comment: Still getting this `Error: xz compression not available` on of them.

Comment: Getting that while trying to install those packages too? You might need to manually download them from an epel repo and install them locally.

Comment: @ihue - you deleted your other question, but `apache2` isn't running - you are seeing your grep process. Use a regular expression to filter it out `ps a | grep [a]pache2` and nothing will return. On CentOS Apache is usually `httpd`, so `service httpd stop`. To have it not start on boot `chkconfig httpd off`.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me here, `service httpd stop` solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Try #4 is working

I got my **Nginx** to install by doing the following

- `yum clean all`
- `yum remove epel-release`
- `yum update`
- `yum install epel-release`
- `yum install nginx -y`